# Passing class to its own member function

Tags: c++

I am moving from Java to C++ and have a simple question. If it is a duplicate please be patient and direct me to the question.

Consider the following classes with their member functions:

```
class Painter {
public:
    void paint(Building *house) {
        // paint the building
    }
};

class Building {
public:
    void passToPainter(){
        painter.paint(this);
    }
private:
    Painter painter;
};
```

The line `painter.paint(this);` is the Java syntax. What is the syntax in C++?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "What is the syntax in C++" - exactly the same ))

Comment: You need an intermediate class that handles interactions between classes. Recursive relations are ill-advised in OOP.

Comment: Thanks all. @Poriferous. Actually I couldn't get it work in the recursive relation that I posted above. It gives error massage "#include nested too deeply." Using an intermediate class solved my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

It's identical. But in C++, `this` is a *pointer* to the object instance, whereas in Java, it's a *reference*.

In C++, `this` will be a `const` pointer to the object if called from a member function marked `const`. That helps achieve program stability.

Comment: In Java, as in C++, `this` is a pointer.  For some reason, the Java documentation calls references what are actually pointers.